# Запуск нового процесса в С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Добрый день!

Я совсем еще новичок, не будьте строги. Задача в том, чтобы по нажатию кнопки (в форме VisualStudio 2012) у меня открылся текстовый документ в ОпенОфис. [Вот по энтой ссылке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) я уже немного с содержанием ознакомился, но что-то где-то не клеится.

Сначала скидываю текст голой формы, затем строчки, которые туда пихал.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HerbstProject2014
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form    
    {

       public Form6();

        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }                     
    }
}
```

Тепереча 2-й вариант:

```
//using теже самые +  
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace HerbstProject2014
{
    public partial class Form6 : Form    
    {

        public Form6()
    void OpenApplication(string ITA14b_Word_Mitschrift)
        {
            InitializeComponent();   
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Process.Start("soffice.bin");
            Process.Start(ITA14b_Word_Mitschrift);
        }

    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( @"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe" );
```

Путь надо прописать

Comment: @Lomalko: Укажите **вместо** `.exe` путь к документу. Должно сработать.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"d:\visual studio 2012\files\ITA14b_Word_Mitschrift");
Вот  так указал путь... выдает ошибку, что-то про вин32. Т.е. программа запускается, но при запуске документа вылетает ошибка. Желтым выделяет эту строку, пишет про вин 32.

Comment: >Желтым выделяет енту строку пишет про вин 32

@Lomalko а что конкретно-то пишет? И потом, как-то сильно подозрительно выглядит ваш путь. Больше похоже на папку, а не на имя файла. Во всяком случае расширение не указано

Comment: а почему по-немецки?)

Comment: @Lomalko: Ну круто. А что именно пишет? Мы должны угадать?

И кстати, а такой файл есть? И ещё, OpenOffice-то у вас установлен?

---
А, вижу. Посмотрите в Exception'е поле `InnerException`, там может быть что-то интересное.